# virtumart product thumbnail image not showing

Tags: joomla2.5

http://lumene-iran.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=2&Itemid=177

What is wrong that my image is not showing up? It is OK in local host but when I upload it, it doesn't show up! I checked that image path is correct in localhost but in the above URL I don't know why but the image path has changed!

Answer (score 1):

Buddy , you need to change the image path in the virtuemart in configuration/templates tab.
You are seeing it on the local because it has taken your local images folder which is in the root (images/virtuemart), but when you move the files to server the path is different one, So you need to change the path in your server too.

one more thing i have seen your source code your include 26 css files which is huge, you need to compress them.

Hope I am clear with my question, let me know if you still don't get the images after changing the path.